# Could somebody breakdown what this contract is doing? Polyscan contract has dropped Matic to a whole load of wallets

Tags: solidity, contract-design

This contract (https://polygonscan.com/address/0x1087e19b00d6916e4de1cf84ad01874bcada8156#internaltx) seemingly dropped 0.25 MATIC into a whole load of wallets over the space of an hour a few days ago.

Could somebody please break down what this contract is attempting to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [decompiled bytecode](https://polygonscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x1087e19b00d6916e4de1cf84ad01874bcada8156), the smart contract looks to be doing exactly what you said that it's doing. Sending 0.25 MATIC to a butt ton of wallets.
The contracts has a single function, the drop function. It takes in all of the wallets that the owner wants to send the MATIC to.
Only the owner is allowed to call the drop function (line 38). Big surprise.
As for the functionality itself, it looks like it sends 0.25 MATIC to addresses as long as they are under a certain amount of MATIC (line 43).

And... that's all it does from what I can tell. As for what the owner is trying to do, not sure. I only clicked on a couple of the addresses that had MATIC sent to them, but it seems like they weren't smart contracts. Maybe he owns all of the wallets. Maybe he's airdropping to followers. Who knows?

Happy hunting!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look through, I assumed this was the case.

One of the wallets is one owned by myself so I was a bit worried as to what the creator was attempting to get out of this.

I guess a further dive is required!